# Nginx country based routing with socket.io

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nginx, proxy, routes

I am trying to run a node.js - mongo db application with nginx as a reverse proxy on digital ocean and mlab.

My website will be used from usa, india, uk and some asian countries potentially.

I have created my droplet on digital ocean in bangalore,  India site. Config - ubuntu 14x, 2GB Ram, 40 GB disk.

I was very surprised to notice that the performance of the site when accessed from USA is terrible. It takes around 25 seconds to load. However the same url can be accessed within 6 seconds from Mumbai, India.

Lot of my files are already minimized, images are compreseed etc.

So what are my options at this time? I can try to do subdomains and have nginx do County based routing to different servers but what impact will it have on socket.io?

Will i have to do have nginx on each individual servers as well? Or just in routing server? What about nginx caching? On which site will i create the server which does routing?

Any examples will be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: 6s from local is still a pretty bad page load time.  How many requests are involved in loading the page?  You may need to do some bundling to reduce the number of requests.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using cloudflare for CDN. I saw significant improvement in speed.